# call method from COM object

Tags: c#, .net, com

third day try to solve my problem, but no luck((
below is my FunnyWorld3.cs file. I registered this component, here is no problem

```
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("Keys.snk")]
public interface IFunnyWorld3
{
    void SayHello(String param);
};

[
  ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)
]

public class FunnyWorld3 : IFunnyWorld3
{   
    public void SayHello(String param)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(param, "FunnyWorld::SayHello metnod was invoked");
    }
};
```

Then I created c# project, with code:

```
Type comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("FunnyWorld3", true);
object comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(comType)
```

What's next? How can i call SayHello method in my project? Please help((

Answer (score 1):

To call the method you need to convert it to the `IFunnyWorld3` type which defines the method.

```
IFunnyWorld3 fw = (IFunnyWorld3)comObj;
fw.SayHello("message");
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but "the type or namespace name IFunnyWorld3 could not be found"

Answer (score 0):

How about casting? If you gained a reference to `object` then you should be able to cast it:

```
IFunnyWorld3 fw3 = (IFunnyWorld3) comObj;
```

Then call your method afterwards. Like

```
fw3.SayHello("Hello, World");
```